# how to send variable value to another function in angularjs in same controller

Tags: angularjs

I have one angularjs function

```
   $rootScope.pagename = [];

     $scope.myFunc= function(event)
       {
        $rootScope.pagename = event.target.id;

       };
```

Now how to access pagename in function demo

```
    function pagename()
{
      alert($rootScope.pagename);
}
```

Comment: Where is your function demo?

Comment: What actually is your problem here? Do you have some exception or `$rootScope.pagename` is unassigned when you're tying to access it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootScope.pageName = [];

$scope.myFunc= function(event) {
    $rootScope.pageName = event.target.id;
    pagename($rootScope.pageName);
};

function pagename(pageName) {
    alert(pageName);
}
```

Comment: Think that should be pagename($rootScope.pageName);

Comment: you want to passing value in function calling

Answer (score 0):

Your question should work as it is, since **$rootScope** is global and you don't have to pass it as a parameter to the second function. However, I think you're assigning an **array** to a value whose type isn't an array, you can try:

```
     $rootScope.pagename = [];

       $scope.myFunc= function(event)
       {
        $rootScope.pagename.push(event.target.id);    
       };
```

And then in the second function, you can do as you did, that is:

```
function pagename()
{
      string name = $rootScope.pagename[0];
      alert(name);
}
```